# Possible to route HTTP traffic through another server?

Tags: networking, ssh, local-area-network

Noob question. I have three remote servers (S1, S2 & S3). One of them has internet connectivity (S1) and the other two (S2 & S3) can **only** access S1 -- for example, I have passwordless SSH set up from S1 to S2 & S3.

This however means that I can do no updates or package management on S2 & S3. Is there a way to make an HTTP request on S2 & S3 that gets tunneled through S1, basically enabling internet access? Does SSH tunneling apply? If so, is there a resource that would guide me step-by-step on how to do that for my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to provide internet (http/https) access to systems which don't have direct internet access is to use a proxy, such as [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). Install the proxy on S1 and configure S2 and S3 to use the proxy (e.g. by setting the http_proxy environment variable or updating the config file of your application)

Comment: Bert, possible to elaborate this a little? What would I need to do on S1 (proxy server?) and on S2 & S3 (client servers?)? I found [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/squid/squid-http-proxy-ubuntu-12-04) which seems to have instructions on what to do on the proxy server S1, but how can I let my client servers S2 & S3 know that they have to route HTTP requests through S1?

Comment: Bert, I was able to piece together the information that I asked for using [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/squid/squid-http-proxy-ubuntu-12-04#basic-setup) and [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-proxy-environment-variable/). Thanks for your help. Other answers are more informative, but your suggestion is the one I implemented, so I am going to mark this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Squid is a good solution as Bert Neef suggested.  Another option I'd recommend is a SOCKS proxy, which uses an SSH tunnel as you've suggested.  It can even work with certain pakage managers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35223/syntax-for-socks-proxy-in-apt-conf

The link is for ubuntu, but tsocks is not ubuntu specific.

Here's an example howto: https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/setting-up-an-ssh-tunnel-with-your-linode-for-safe-browsing

Or just google 'socks proxy ssh'

Answer (score 1):

## Through Proxy

The proxy will make the trafic redirect depending of the client request

#### Advantages

- You can redirect your trafic as you want (matching domain name for example)
- Access log are centralised on server 1

## Through Apache

If you are using Apache on server 1 you can create virtual host to proxy your request to server 2 & 3

#### Advantages

- You can use different domain name to access each web server
- Web logs will be centralised on the server 1
- You can use a central auth
- You can block suspicous web trafic using apache rules on server 1 before accessing to server 2 & 3

#### Incovenients

- to connect to ssh 2 & 3 you will have to connect through server 1 then use ssh command to connect to server 2 & 2

## Through NAT

If you use a NAT (Network Translating Adress), you can set a couple of external IP+port linked to internal IP+Port

#### Advantages

- Server are like directly connected to internet so you can access them just with the couple of IP+port

#### Incovenients

- You will need 1 port for each web server and each ssh